# Opencart 2.1.1 Menu Link Issue

Tags: opencart

I am using OpenCart v 2.1.1.

In the admin area, the settings area indicates that the theme is set to Default.

On the server, I navigated to catalog -> view -> theme -> default -> template -> common
and opened up the header.tpl file for editing.

Inside the header.tpl file, I located line 115 which appears to be the last item

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
```

Then on the next line I added in:

```
<li><a href="index.php?route=information/contact">Contact Us</a><li>
```

I Saved Changes, refreshed web page, and the Contact Us link does not appear in the blue menubar.

What have I done wrong..

Answer (score 0):

seems you add this line to the not correct place. you should add it before the last `</ul>` tag. this is 114 line in OC2.1 version.

```
<li><a href="index.php?route=information/contact">Contact Us</a><li>
      </ul>
```

The last part of the header.tpl:

```
 <?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <div class="container">
      <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs"><?php echo $text_category; ?></span>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="dropdown-inner">
                  <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>


<li><a href="index.php?route=information/contact">Contact Us</a><li>


          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I have checked it works with default. Of course do not forget clear cache of your browser.

Comment: I cleared the cache, moved the above li to line 114 in the header.tpl file, saved changes, refreshed web page, and lnk did not show up.

Comment: What else could it be?

Comment: Edited my first post.

Comment: I have done the above and it still isn't showing up. What else could I check?

Comment: If you use vqmod delete all vqcache files. Delete all files except index.html from system/storage/cache. clear browser cache. It should work.

Comment: Thank  you. I just did that now and the changes, the Contact Us link I added still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete the cache of the template engine, else it won't update the cached template.